# Apply map() to only a subset of elements in a Java stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible, with the Java stream API to apply a map() not on the whole stream (a.k.a. not on every element which is streamed), but only on a set of elements which pass a filter? The filter however should not filter out elements. The result should be a stream of the original elements, but on some of them, a map() has been applied.

Pseudocode:

```
List<Integer>.stream.filterAndMap(x -> if (x>10) {x+2}).toList();
```

Comment: Just returns `x` itself for the elements that you don't want to change.

Comment: Sweeper is right. In your example, this would be `.map(x -> (x > 10 ? x + 2 : x))`

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn’t downvote, but I would assume it’s because this question does not show much research effort, and its obvious answer makes it unuseful.

Comment: Thank you all. The answers are totally legit and usable. I asked this question b.c. I was wondering if there actually is such a method (a combination of filter() and map()) which I never heard of. And I thought it might be interesting for others. Sorry for not researching it beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `if … else …`

Just return the value unchanged if it does not meet your requirement for modification.

```java
List < Integer > integers = List.of( 1 , 7 , 42 );
List < Integer > modified =
        integers
                .stream()
                .map( integer -> {
                    if ( integer > 10 ) { return integer + 2; }
                    else { return integer; }
                } )
                .toList();
```

> modified.toString() = [1, 7, 44]

## Ternary operator

Or shorten that code by using a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator#Java) as [commented by MC Emperor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897938/apply-map-to-only-a-subset-of-elements-in-a-java-stream/74898018#comment132175730_74897938).

```java
List < Integer > integers = List.of( 1 , 7 , 42 );
List < Integer > modified =
        integers
                .stream()
                .map( integer -> ( integer > 10 ) ? ( integer + 2 ) : integer )
                .toList();
```

Comment: Good answer! **Nitpicking:** The parentheses with the ternary operator look good (and maybe make it easier for a beginner to understand it), but they are unnecessary i.e. `integer -> ( integer > 10 ) ? ( integer + 2 ) : integer` can be written as `integer -> integer > 10 ? integer + 2 : integer`.

Answer (score 1):

See how starting with intention-named pseudo-code pays always off.

#### Naming

The pseudo-instruction `filterAndMap(x -> if (x>10) {x+2})` is violating [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) at least by the name containing "And" to clue two responsibilities.

To resolve with Java Streams-API would suggest:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(predicate)   // filter means discarding elements from result
    .map(mappingFunction)  // map applies to filtered elements only
    .toList();
```

But then the resulting list is filtered by the predicate or condition, hence not having original size.

#### Rephrase intention: Conditionally Map

Search for [`[java] conditionally map`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20conditionally%20map). Some answers show *if statements* or *ternary operator* to implement the conditional.

Still the primary step is `map`. Inside implement the conditional. Whether using a lambda or a function-reference, this decides how to map:

```
if (predicate.apply(x)) {
   return modify(x);
}

return x;  // default: unmodified identity
```

This is Basil's approach `.map( integer -> ( integer > 10 ) ? ( integer + 2 ) : integer )`.

#### Why streams?

Assume some of the list elements stay the same, where only some are modified on condition. Like your requirement states:

> stream of the original elements, but on some of them, a map() has been applied.

Wouldn't it be clearer then, to use a for-each loop with conditional modification to have the list elements modified in-place:

```
List<Integer> intList = List.of(1, 7, 42);

// can also be a intList.forEach with Consumer 
for (i : intList) {
    if (i > 10) {
        i = i + 2;
    }
});
```